# How to build self-referential associations in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, join, self-reference

I'm having some troubles writing a Rails app that organizes scientific papers.

Each paper has many references (other papers) -> A paper cites many papers
Each paper has many citations (other papers, the inverse relationship) -> A paper is being cited by many papers

My intention is to be able to access a papers references and citations like this

```
@paper = Paper.first
@paper.references => [Papers that @paper is citing]
@paper.citations  => [Papers that @paper is being cited by]
```

Here are the steps I took:

```
# console
rails g model paper title  # Generate Paper model
rails g model citation paper_id:integer reference_id:integer  # Generate Citation Model

# app/models/paper.rb
class Paper < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relations
  has_many :reference_relations, class_name: 'Citation'
  has_many :citation_relations, class_name: 'Citation', foreign_key: 'reference_id'

  # References and citations
  has_many :references, through: :reference_relations
  has_many :citations, through: :citation_relations, source: :paper

  attr_accessible :title
end

# app/models/citation.rb
class Citation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :paper                           # Source of the reference, paper that is citing
  belongs_to :reference, class_name: 'Paper'  # Paper that is being referenced and cited

  # attr_accessible :reference_id # This should not be accessible, should it?
end
```

Now I try building a reference:

```
p = Paper.first
r = Paper.last
p.references.build(reference_id: r.id)
```

When I try to build a citation however, I get an `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: reference_id` error. I first assumed that the attr_accessible in the Citation model would be nescessary to set, it turns out however that ActiveRecord is trying to assign the reference_id to a paper instance and not to a new citation instance.

**What is the best way to connect two paper to one another and how do I build these connections?**

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please add your Reference model code.

Comment: I have no specific reference model. I consider a reference to be a paper listed in the bibliography of another paper, and a citation to be the inverse of that.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I added some clarification about what I am trying to achieve and edited the code a litte. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: tbh I find the use of relations and references and the class name changes confusing.  My best advice would be to try and go simpler, not add more.  Try again without using those words.  Be very simple and post that.  I will try the beginning of a simpler answer.

Comment: I try to build a reference_relation, not references, that was my mistake. `p = Paper.first; l = Paper.last; l.reference_relation << p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is self-referential because the connection is through the citation, not directly on the Paper itself.

So I would approach it like this:

```
Paper 
has_many :citation_papers
has_many :citations, :through => citation_papers

Citation
has_many :citation_papers
has_many :papers, :through citation_papers

CitationPaper # Needs the two ID's
belongs_to :paper
belongs_to :citation
```